# LCD menu creation library

Tags: library, c, embedded-systems

I have to create a C application for some embedded system with Linux which is to create and control menu on the device's LCD. Is ncurses library suitable for my needs? If no, are there another (free if possible) libraries for this? Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a device driver for the specific LED? At the very least, it should have an API/SDK. Have you contacted the manufacturer, or looked at the support section of their website?